# I am using a previous app but getting error in UIResponder.h

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiresponder

I am using a app of previous developer ,but when i compile it ,ig shows 5 errors at UIResponder.h and UIEvent.h

**error 1:**

> file/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIEvent.h:38:0 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIEvent.h:38: error: expected ':' before ';' token

**error2:**

> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIResponder.h:15:0 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIResponder.h:15: error: expected ')' before 'UIResponder'

**error 3:**

> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIResponder.h:17:0 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIResponder.h:17: error: expected '{' before '-' token

**error4:**

> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIResponder.h:42:0 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIResponder.h:42: warning: '@end' must appear in an @implementation context

**error5:**

> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIResponder.h:58:0 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIResponder.h:58: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'UIResponder'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once check in which version of iPhone OS you are installing your App. Once check the targets and change the base sdk and deployment sdk as required.

Comment: Satya ,thanks for reply I was using 3.1 and app is developed for 2.1

Comment: once change the base sdk to 3.1 in the targets. Clean all the targets and and build the app.

Answer (score 1):

Try by removing all the linked frameworks and link from your library.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the frameworks used in the application. Add back all the frameworks and do a clean build of the application. This might help.

Comment: Yes,I removed all frameworks and added then I also,clean .bit same errors are accuring please help